# popoverContentSize not responding in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I Have a piece of code which is as follows:
self.popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(248.0, 216.0);

This works fine in iOS 7 and below. However, it doesn't respond to CGSizeMake in iOS 8. No matter what the value is specified with in CGSizeMake(), it takes the same default size.

Please reply with an alternative code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take two steps to solve this

**Step One:**

As an immediate fix, you can set `preferredContentSize` property of UIViewController

> ```
> [popoverViewController setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(248.0,216.0)];
> ```

before initalizing `UIPopoverController`

> ```
> UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverViewController];
> ```

**Step Two:**

In iOS8, `UIPopoverPresentationController` is getting introduced as a replacement of `UIPopoverController`

> ```
> if ([popoverViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)]) {
>    popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
>    [popoverViewController setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(248.0,216.0)];
>
>    UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverPresentation = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController;
>    [popoverPresentation setSourceView:_sourceView];
>    [popoverPresentation setSourceRect:_sourceRect];
>    [popoverPresentation setPermittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp];
>
>    [self presentViewController:popoverViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
> } else {
>    //existing code...
> }
> ```

As of now, [pre-release documentation](http://goo.gl/QoYgmV) is available for further reference.